# How to loop an array inside an array with React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Hello I have some data I am trying to display with react that looks like this

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAYSb.png)

there is an Options array inside of the Poll array. 
How do I display the options array with react when I am already mapping the Poll array? This is what i have so far:

```
renderPost(posts){

        return posts.map((post) => {
        return (
            <div>
            <h3>{post.question}</h3>


            </div>
               );
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
renderPost(posts){
  return posts.map(post =>
    <div>
      <h3>{post.question}</h3>
      <ul>
        {post.options.map(option => 
          <li>{option.title}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply but im getting "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: I had to guess at your data model, you’ll need to adapt it to your specific needs

Answer (score 0):

You should never forget add a key to the jsx element when generate them in loop. The key should be unique and key should be from data, if your data doesn't contain unique id per object then use index as a key like below

Unique id as key from data

```
return posts.map(post =>
    <div key={post.id}>
      <h3>{post.question}</h3>
      <ul>
        {post.options.map(option => 
          <li key={option.id}>{option.title}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
```

Use index as a key if you don't have unique id in data array

```
return posts.map((post, index) =>
    <div key={`Key${index}`}>
      <h3>{post.question}</h3>
      <ul>
        {post.options.map((option, i) => 
          <li key={`Key${i}`}>{option.title}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
```