# A loop in a loop of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have a JSON file for my data:

```
{
  "EIC": {
    "id": "EIC",
    "text": "Want to do a quick word game?",
    "replies": ["Sure", "Later"]
  },
  "YMB": {
    "id": "YMB",
    "text": "Okay, tomorrow. Cya!",
    "replies": ["bye Woebot"],
  }
}
```

I want to render the array of replies so we can see the different answers possible in the HTML.
Here's my component at the moment:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import style from "../styles/entry.css";

import * as allornothing from '../allornothing.json';

class EntryList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: Object.values(allornothing)
    }
  }

  renderReplies(replies) {
    return replies.map((reply) => {
        return (
            <div class="entry-body col-12">
                <button class="back">{ reply }</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row" id="entries-list">
        {this.state.list.map(function(entry) {
          return (
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              <div class="entry col-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="entry-header col-12">
                    <div class="entry-id">
                      <span>{entry.id}</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>{entry.text}</p>
                  </div>

                  { this.renderReplies(entry.replies) }

                  <div class="entry-manage col-12">
                    <div class="row">

                      <span class="manage-button">
                        <i class="fas fa-comments"></i> Add new answer
                      </span>

                      <span class="manage-button">
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Modify
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EntryList
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderReplies' of undefined

While, if I replace `{ this.renderReplies(entry.replies) }` by `console.log(entry.replies)` it does print the replies of every question.
I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706706/how-to-loop-an-array-inside-an-array-with-react) before coming up with the `renderReplies` function but I just get the same error...
Also if I put `{entry.replies}` in my html code, it does render a list of strings too.

Does anyone have an idea of why I get this error and how I can display my list of replies? Thanks.

Comment: Inside of the constructor put `this.renderReplies = this.renderReplies.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

```
{this.state.list.map(function(entry) {
```

Change this to be an arrow function instead. Arrow functions take their value of `this` from the context in which they are defined, which means inside the function `this` will continue to be your component

```
{this.state.list.map((entry) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be not binding the function to the class. Try adding the following line of code to your constructor function:

```
this.renderReplies = this.renderReplies.bind(this)
```

Alternatively you could use an arrow function to maintain the context of 'this'. Which would look like:

```
renderReplies = replies => { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because `this.renderReplies` is called inside a `function(){}` which overrides `this`. You can avoid this by using an arrow function like so:

```
this.state.list.map(entry => {
...
{ this.renderReplies(entry.replies) }
...
});
```

You can read more about `this` on arrow functions [here](https://www.quora.com/In-JavaScript-what-are-some-of-the-differences-between-an-arrow-function-vs-an-anonymous-function)